# Problem in -[CALayer setBorderColor:]

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextview

I want to have border around my textview; for that, I did the following:

```
textView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
textView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

I am getting the following warning:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'setBorderColor:' from incompatible pointer type
```

Update1 : my border is not visible

Answer (score 19):

Your problem is that `-[CALayer setBorderColor:]` takes an object of type `CGColorRef`. What you need to do is convert your color object to conform:

```
textView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
```

I hope that helped!